# Incomplete data while fetching through Named Query JPA2.0

Tags: jpa

I have an entity named ReqestDetail and done association and mapping as below snippet:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="STATUS_C")
private StatusCode statusCode;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to RequestAddressDetail
@OneToMany(mappedBy="requestDetail")
private List<RequestAddressDetail> addressDetails;
```

I have created below Named Query to fetch the details on the basis of address.

```
  TypedQuery<RequestDetail> query = em.createQuery( "SELECT t FROM RequestDetail t" +
                " LEFT JOIN t.employeeDetail e " +
                " LEFT JOIN t.addressDetails ao " +
                " LEFT JOIN t.addressDetails ad " +
                " WHERE (e.employeeI IN ( :employeeIds ) ) AND " +
                " (ao.postI = :postO  AND ao.addressTypeC = :addressTypeO " +
                " AND ad.postI = :PostD  AND ad.addressTypeC = :addressTypeD )" ,
                RequestDetail.class );
```

However, when I call query.getResultList(), it is only giving me data of RequestDetail Entity but not of the mapping joins I have mentioned in that entity.

Please advise...

Answer (score 0):

why do you think it should give you some joined objects? Your candidate for the query is RequestDetail, so it gives that. If you did a `JOIN FETCH` then you can fetch other fields, but you haven't done that (so change those `LEFT JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN FETCH`) - a JOIN (without FETCH) is simply a convenience way of forming the query.. Alternatively you could set the entity graph to fetch, or set the fetch on the field itself if you wanted those fetching

Comment: That's right Neil, but If I change the query using FETCH then how would I create condition for address check in where clause, could you help me writing that query

Comment: Well some JPA implementations allow aliases to be specified on the LEFT JOIN FETCH (just like a LEFT JOIN) not that the JPA spec includes that possibility. Also that is where EntityGraphs allow much more control ... *when using JPA2.1*. "Touching" a field of the returned object whilst still in the transaction is the only other way of getting them pulled back. The JPA spec is the weakness here